# I have created a LOGIN SIGNIN FORM. I have also been able to create the hidden form so they should show up separately

Tags: javascript, html

I have checked the code and it looks as though everything is correct. But when I click on the "create account, both the Login in form AND the Create Account form are on the same screen. BUT when I click on the Already have an account, the LOGIN page shows up by itself.  I have included the code to show what I have...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title> Login Form</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href=" /assets/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;400;500&display=swap" 
     rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=" ./src/main.css">
  <head>
  <body>
</header>
<div class="container">
      <form class="form  form--hidden" id="login"></form>
         <h1 class="form__title">Login</h1> 
         <div class="form__message .form__message--error"></div>
         <div class="form__input-group">
           <input type="text" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="Username or email">
           <div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
           <div class="form__input-group">
             <input type="password" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="Password">
             <div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
         </div>
         <button class="form__button" type="submit">Continue</button>
        <p class="form__text">
         <a class="form__link" href=" ./" id="forgotPassword">Forgot your password? Click here!</a>
        </p>
        <p class="form__text">
          <a  class="form__link" id="linkCreateAccount"> Dont have an account? Create One</a>
        </p>
      </form> 
      <form class="form" id="createAccount">
         <h1 class="form__title">Create Account</h1> 
         <div class="form__message .form__message--error"></div>
         <div class="form__input-group">
           <input type="text" id="signupUsername" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="Username">
           <div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="form__input-group">
           <input type="text" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="Email Address">
           <div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="form__input-group">
           <input type="password" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="Password">
           <div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="form__input-group">
           <input type="password" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="Confirm password">
           <div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
         </div>
         <button class="form__button" type="submit">Continue</button>
         <p class="form__text">
          <a class="form__link" href=" ./" id="linkLogin">Already have an account? Sign in</a>
        </p>
      </form>
 </div>    

<script src="./src/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: rewording the statement in the question: I have created a LOGIN SIGNIN FORM. It has been create so one of the pages is a hidden form.  But both show up on the "create account" page.

Comment: Here is the link to the site.   http://127.0.0.1:5500/.vscode/LOGIN%20SIGNUP/